# Django validation returns two errors instead of one

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-views

as the questions states i receive two errors in my template. Here is the code

```
def create(request):

full_content = forms.InputForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    full_content = forms.InputForm(request.POST)
    
    if full_content.is_valid(): 
        title = full_content.cleaned_data["title"]
        content = full_content.cleaned_data["content"] 

        if full_content.clean_title():#Works                
            full_content.create(title, content)
            context= {
                'title' : util.get_page_name(title),
                'entry' : util.get_entry(title),
            }                
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html",context)           
    
    #From here on its not valid:
    context = {
        'form':full_content
    }
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", context)      
return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
    'form':full_content
})
```

And the forms.clean_title():

```
def clean_title(self):
    title_name = self.cleaned_data.get("title")
    filename = f'entries/{title_name}.md'
        
    if default_storage.exists(filename):
        raise ValidationError("This title is already taken")

    return title_name
```

Ofcourse the create.html aswell:

```
<h3>Create new entry</h3>
<form action="{% url 'create'%}" method="POST">
    
    {{ form.title.errors }}
    
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{form.as_p}}
    </table>
    
    <button type="submit" value="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Any ideas why i get two bullets?:

- This title is already taken
- This title is already taken

Comment: `{{form.as_p}}` includes the errors.  No need for `{{ form.title.errors }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need `{{ form.title.errors }}`. `{{form.as_p}}` is also show errors. So remove it.

```
<h3>Create new entry</h3>
<form action="{% url 'create'%}" method="POST">
    
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{form.as_p}}
    </table>
    
    <button type="submit" value="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Other Methods than ```{{form.as_p}}```
   ```{{ form.as_table }}``` will render them as table cells wrapped in <tr> tags
   ```{{ form.as_ul }}``` will render them wrapped in <li> tags